# Working with cookies from a static page

Tags: javascript, cookies

There is a static (not CGI, not PHP) HTML page (in fact, many such pages, residing in different directories).

I need to store and read cookies for that pages (one cookies for all pages).

I guess, this can be done using JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Javascript to play with cookies.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

[Source](http://ppk.developpez.com/tutoriels/javascript/gestion-cookies-javascript/#LV)